# Глагольно-именные сочетания со словом "отношение"

Tags: семантика

Какие глаголы можно употреблять со словом отношение, помимо "выражать отношение"?

Answer (score 2):

См. здесь:
https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

С глаголами (аргумент)

иметь   отношение

выяснять    отношения

наладить    отношения

поддерживать    отношения

строить отношения

установить  отношения

изменить своё   отношение

сохранить   отношения

вступать в  отношения

испортить   отношения

касаться    отношений

находиться в    отношениях

разорвать   отношения

и мн. др.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, что со словом "отношение" (в единственном числе) употребляется не так уж и много глаголов:
иметь, изменить, измениться, менять, определить, пересмотреть, сложиться, сохраниться, складываться, определяться, сохраняться, испортить...

Другие глаголы можно посмотреть здесь:
[Словарь глагольной сочетаемости непредметных имен](http://dict.ruslang.ru/abstr_noun.php?act=search&noun=%EE%F2%ED%EE%F8%E5%ED%E8%E5&adj=&verb=&base=&semclass=&subclass=&mood=&phase=&good=&size=&neg=&order=)